Cannot send snapshot XXX recursively: snapshot dataset/nestedDataset@XXX does not exist
I performed a snapshot pruning 2 days ago that resulted in some issues on the snapshots. I incurred some light data loss because, I suspect, some snapshots were created as "clone snapshots" and once the original snapshot was deleted, the other snapshots were recursively deleted and as such, the data is gone. I was lucky that some of my jails were running and so a busy snapshot could not be deleted.
The pool is now in a weird state where when I try to perform a replication with the flags "from scratch" and "almost full dataset", from my source (MARS) onto a brand new pool (BMARS), I receive the following errors (this is an extract):
skipping snapshot MARS/mymedia@francesco-202408021221 because it was created after the destination snapshot (francesco-202407311813)
skipping snapshot MARS/iocage/jails/znc_1@francesco-202408021221 because it was created after the destination snapshot (francesco-202407311813)
cannot send MARS@francesco-202407311813 recursively: snapshot MARS/iocage/jails/znc_1/root@francesco-202407311813 does not exist
warning: cannot send 'MARS@francesco-202407311813': backup failed
cannot receive: failed to read from stream")

Whatever I did, I wasn't able to replicate the pool anymore, and I definitely would like to backup my data.
I don't think the skipping is the source of the issue, but rather the cannot send MARS@francesco-202407311813 recursively: snapshot MARS/iocage/jails/znc_1/root@francesco-202407311813 does not exist. This missing snapshot seems to be the actual source of the problem.
What are my options to correct the error and be able to perform a full replication again?
I'm afraid of deleting snapshots and ending up losing data again.
Keep in mind that:

I was able to perform a full replication right now by creating a new snapshot with a different naming schema and requested to perform the full replication following the new naming schema (francesco-fix1-202408021221). In this way only one snapshot was replicated (ok), and all the data with it was copied over. This is better than having no backups
I'm concerned that all the "skips" are about snapshots that happened in the future. I definitely want those, because I want that data
I don't care about previous snapshots as long as I don't lose the data. I'm pretty sure there are more "clone snapshots" around because TrueNAS creates the jails as "clone jails" by default

The problematic snapshot is MARS/iocage/jails/znc_1/root@francesco-202407311813, the most recent snapshot that I would like to have is francesco-202408021221, but as you can see, it says skipping because it was created after the destination snapshot.
Would creating a new snapshot for MARS/iocage/jails/znc_1/root and name it francesco-202407311813 potentially fix the issue, even if the snapshot is created with the current state of the data?
